# VBA Copy Destination with formats not just values

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which goes to the end of a row then adds text which is in a specified cell of another sheet. This works well however now I want to modify this to copy the text and the formatting that in place.

I thought the change `If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Value = Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy Destination: Exit For` would work but this gives me an error.

I also tried setting the cell I wanted to copy as a range and referring to that however this also gave me the value only and not the formatting.

I also tried `If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Value = Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy: Exit For` and the result was entered as True.

Is there a simple way I should be doing this?

```
Sub AddText()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set ws = Sheets("Selection")
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
               If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Value = Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Value: Exit For
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Syntax is `Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy cell`

Comment: I changed the .Value to .Copy cell and got a Compile error: Expected: end of statement. So I'm still getting a syntax error.

Comment: Get rid of that horrible `:`-syntax to concatenate 2 statements on one line. Create a `If`...`End IF` Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up 2 different things

a) Assigning a value

```
cell.Value = Sheets("Text").Range("A2").value 
cell = Sheets("Text").Range("A2")    ' Basically the same, you will see this very often
```

This will copy the content (and only the content) of one cell to another.

b) Copy & Paste

```
Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy cell
Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy Destination:=cell  ' Synonym
```

This will copy the whole Information of the source cell ("A2") into the destination. It is basically the same as Press Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in Excel

c) Just to be complete: You can also use `PasteSpecial` to copy only certain parts (formatting, formula, value, number format...). This needs to be done with 2 lines:

```
Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy
cell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

There are lots of options for that, (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) and you know that command from `PasteSpecial` in Excel.

So what you probably want is

```
 For Each cell In ws.Columns(1).Cells
     If IsEmpty(cell) Then 
         Sheets("Text").Range("A2").Copy cell
         Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of this. Very much appreciated and you also answered another question I was working on.